# Query disk performance in VMware database

Tags: sql-server, performance, query, vmware

i need help to build a query to retrieve disks performance from VMware database. The query must bring the host LUN or the VM disk, and their respective IO and latency.

I found the view `VPXV_HIST_STAT_DAILY` with the performance collection, but i did not find a away to connect this view with the disk.

Thanks.

Comment: did you check [this post from sqlskills](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/querying-the-vmware-vcenter-database-vcdb-for-performance-and-configuration-information/)  and [this mssqltips](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3211/gather-information-from-vmware-vcenter-vcdb-about-sql-server/) ?

Comment: @KinShah yes, but the relationship between the view `VPXV_HIST_STAT_DAILY` and the disks table has not been explained.